# Print value of drop down populated using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I would want to store the value of the second drop down in a variable populated after selecting the first drop down to use it further in my PHP code. But not sure how to do this.

JQuery Code

```
No=new Array("20%","30%","40%","50%");
Yes=new Array('0%');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

  $('#cat').change(function(){
    populateSelect();
});

});


function populateSelect(){
cat = $('#cat').val();
$('#item').html('');


if(cat=='No'){
    No.forEach(function(t) { 
        $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');

    });
}

if(cat=='Yes'){
    Yes.forEach(function(t) {
        $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
    });
}

}
```

Select html code

```
<form name="dropdown" method="post" action="">
<select id="cat">
    <option value="">***Please Select***</option>
    <option value="No">B</option>
    <option value="Yes">C</option>
</select>

<select id="item"></select>

<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Cateogry".$_POST[cat];
    echo "Item".$_POST[item];
}
```

Comment: With the input submit you are changing page, you can do it with Ajax and with the response you can store what you want (as example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your inputs, and put quotes around your array keys, and change your submit button to be of type `submit` not `button`:

```
<form name="dropdown" method="post" action="">
<select id="cat" name="cat">
    <option value="">***Please Select***</option>
    <option value="No">B</option>
    <option value="Yes">C</option>
</select>

<select id="item" name="item"></select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Cateogry".$_POST['cat'];
    echo "Item".$_POST['item'];
}
```

Comment: sorry for being so dumb as I am newbie for this. My code for HTML and PHP is same as you mentioned however, it still does not work. On clicking submit nothing happens.

Comment: @Roger I missed an important detail - you where using the wrong type attribute for your submit button, see edit

Comment: Yes the page gets submitted however it fails to print the Item which get populated after the first drop down (cat) is selected

Comment: Found a minor mistake that I did. It is working now. Thanks for quick help :)